# Issue with MySql Routine

Tags: mysql, routines

I am having an issue with making a MySql Routine.

Here is the code:

```
DELIMITER '$$';
CREATE PROCEDURE User.Login(IN UserName CHAR(32), IN PWord CHAR(32))
BEGIN
Select `userID`, `userType`, `userMainEmail`, `groupID`
    From `at_users`
    Where `userName` = UserName And `userPass` = PWord
    LIMIT 1
FOR UPDATE;

    Update `at_users`
    Set `lastLoginAt` = now()
    Where `userName` = UserName And `userPass` = PWord;
END$$
```

What it's supposed to do is a simple login task that's done just about everywhere...   get a users record, then update the table with now()

What I am getting on creating this is:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your     MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 12
```

Line 12 is the line right before END$$

Yes, all fields and tables exist. :)

EDIT:  NEW CODE

```
DELIMITER //;
CREATE PROCEDURE User.Login(IN UserName CHAR(32), IN PWord CHAR(32))
BEGIN
Select `userID`, `userType`, `userMainEmail`, `groupID`
    From `at_users`
    Where `userName` = UserName And `userPass` = PWord
    LIMIT 1
FOR UPDATE;

    Update `at_users`
    Set `lastLoginAt` = now()
    Where `userName` = UserName And `userPass` = PWord;
END//
DELIMITER ;
```

I am trying this exact code from the command line, after logging in and selecting the proper database to USE.

After the last line 'DELIMITER ;' nothing happens and I stay at the -> line

Comment: Check the syntax: [DELIMITER](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-procedure.html). It should be `DELIMITER $$;` without quotes.

Comment: p.s.   I'm trying to run this through phpmyadmin SQL tab.   I will try directly on the server in a little while.

Comment: Add `DELIMITER ;` after the last line (after `END$$`)

Comment: tried that too.   when I do that, I get no error, but the Routine is not created

Comment: ok.  I'm attempting to do this from shell as well, and nothing is happenning.  The new method I am trying is up in the question

Comment: little update, I took out the ; from the first DELIMITER line, and put in the rest of the code.   Now I am getting an error 'Unknown database `User`'

Comment: My first comment was incorrect. It must be `DELIMITER $$` without quotes and **without semi colon**. I tried it in phpmyadmin and it works, the procedure gets created.

Comment: Then remove `User.` in front of the procedure name, to create the procedure in the currently selected database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it.

Here is the code I ended up having to use:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE UserLogin(IN UserName CHAR(32), IN PWord CHAR(32))
    BEGIN
        Select `userID`, `userType`, `userMainEmail`, `groupID`
        From `at_users`
        Where `userName` = UserName And `userPass` = PWord
        LIMIT 1
        FOR UPDATE;

        Update `at_users`
        Set `lastLoginAt` = now()
        Where `userName` = UserName And `userPass` = PWord;
    END//
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: You may keep `$$` as delimiter. This is entirely up to you, as long as the delimiter is used nowhere else in the code.

Comment: How is this too localized???!!!